# How to execute a string in a stored procedure in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, exec

I create a stored procedure and call it:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_Maketing]
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @Action nvarchar(50) = null,
    @Brank nvarchar(10) = null,
    @DateImport nvarchar(30) = null,
    @Like nvarchar(30) = null,
    @Month int = 0,
    @Year int = 0,
    @DateUpDate nvarchar(30) = null,
    @SchemeCode nvarchar(30) = null,
    @Teritory nvarchar(50) = null,
    @FromDate nvarchar(30) = null,
    @ToDate nvarchar(30) = null,
    @CouponCode nvarchar(10) = null,
    @BarCode nvarchar(20) = null,
    @FromPoint int = 0,
    @ToPoint int = 0
AS
BEGIN
    If(@Action = 'GETCUSTOMEROFSTORE')
    Begin
        If(@Brank = 'VASCARA')
        Begin
            Set @Like = 'VAS%'
            Set @DateImport = '01/01/2015'
        End

        If(@Brank='CATWALK')
        Begin
            Set @Like = 'CAT%'
            Set @DateImport = '05/01/2015'
        End

        Set @StrSQL = 'Select MSC.[Card No_], MSC.[Account No_], MC.Name, MC.[First Name],
                              MC.[Middle Name], MC.Surname, MSC.[Club Code], MSC.[Scheme Code], ISNULL(TH.[Sale Point], 0) As ''Sale Point'',
                              ISNULL(TH1.[Sale Point], 0) As ''Sale Point Of Year'',
                              MC.[Date of Birth], MC.[Address], MC.[Address 2], MC.[Teritory], MC.Country_VAS, MC.City,  MC.[Phone No_],
                              MC.[Mobile Phone No_], MSC.[Allocated to Store], 
                              MC.[E-Mail], UPS.[Last Scheme], UPS.[Current Scheme], UPS.Date 
                     FROM [MASTER$Membership Card] MSC
                     left join (
        select A.[Account No_], A.[Name], A.[First Name],   A.[Middle Name], A.Surname, A.[Date of Birth],
        A.[Address], A.[Address 2], B.[Name] AS ''Teritory'',   A.Country_VAS, A.City,  A.[Phone No_], A.[Mobile Phone No_],A.[E-Mail]
        from [MASTER$Member Contact] A
        left join (
            select * from [MASTER$Territory]
        ) B on B.[Code]= A.[Territory Code]
    ) MC on MC.[Account No_]=MSC.[Account No_]

    left join (
        Select Sum([Points]) as ''Sale Point'', [Account No_] From [MASTER$Member Point Entry]
        Where [Member Scheme] like '''+@Like+'''
        Group By [Account No_]
    )TH on TH.[Account No_] =MSC.[Account No_]

    left join (
        select Sum([Points]) as ''Sale Point'', [Account No_] from [MASTER$Member Point Entry]
        where [Entry Type]=0 and  [Member Scheme] like '''+@Like+'''
        group by [Account No_]
    )TH1 on TH1.[Account No_] =MSC.[Account No_]

    Left Join (
        select Distinct * from [MASTER$Member Account Upgrade Entry]
        where [Action Type]=0 and ([Active]=1)
        and [Date]>=CONVERT(date,'''+@DateImport+''',103) 
        and [Current Scheme] like '''+@Like+'''
    ) UPS on UPS.[Account No_]=MSC.[Account No_]

    Where MSC.[Club Code] like '''+@Like+''' and MSC.[Account No_] in(
        Select [Account No_] from [MASTER$Membership Card]
        Where  '+@Teritory+'
        and  [Club Code] like '''+@Like+'''
    )'

    EXEC(@StrSQL) 
  End
End
```

When I call it with query:

```
exec SP_Maketing @Action = N'GETCUSTOMEROFSTORE', 
                 @Brank = 'VASCARA',
                 @Teritory = N' [Allocated to Store] = ''VNB01'''
```

it's ok!

But, when I call it with query:

```
exec SP_Maketing @Action = N'GETCUSTOMEROFSTORE', 
                 @Brank = 'VASCARA',
                 @Teritory = N'[Allocated to Store] = ''VNB01'' or  [Allocated to Store] = ''VNB02'''
```

it shows an error:

> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 551
>   Invalid column name 'Allocated to and  [Club Code'.

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You declared the parameter length `@Teritory nvarchar(50)` as 50 and passing a value which is having length more than 50.This causes truncation and hence the error message.Increase the size accordingly, probably to 100 in this case.

`AND` has priority over `OR`. So it is better to use brackets when you use both.After increasing the size, try this

```
exec SP_Maketing @Action = N'GETCUSTOMEROFSTORE', 
                 @Brank = 'VASCARA',
                 @Teritory = N'([Allocated to Store] = ''VNB01'' or  [Allocated to Store] = ''VNB02'')'
```